# Exported csv SAS table cannot be imported

Tags: csv, sas

I exported my SAS table in the form of a csv file into a different folder for me to use with a different program using this code that worked:

```
PROC EXPORT data=CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_&thestate.
outfile="&whichfolder.CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_&thestate..csv"
dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter=",";
run;
```

Using a different program in a different folder I am trying to import the data via this code:

```
LIBNAME Home "/sasdata/sasperm2/act_cfr/fr/SJR/AmFam_vs_ISO_Compare/" ;       
%let Filepath = /sasdata/sasperm2/act_cfr/fr/SJR/AmFam_vs_ISO_Compare/;

%sdwlogin;
RUN;

%let thestate = OR;
%let policyyr = 2012;

/*---- ISO_Compare ----*/
data Work.CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_&thestate.;

length Policy $10.;

infile "&Filepath/CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_&thestate..csv" DELIMITER=','  TERMSTR=CRLF     LRECL=2500  FIRSTOBS=2  MISSOVER  DSD;

input Policy;
run;
```

The program runs but I am getting no data. I shortened the variable list to make the code easier to read. When I manually copy and re-paste the data into a different csv file and re-name it the same "CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_OR.csv" then it works in my program. My initial reason to incorporate this code was to get rid of the manual process... so if anybody has any hints I would be very thankful.

Comment: Why are you going to CSV and back?  Why not just save the SAS dataset to a permanent library?

Comment: Are you initially creating the csv file with CRLF?  The fact that it works after you save it (I'm guessing in excel?) seems to point in that direction.  In other words, is the first program running on a linux system?  Then you don't want to use the `TERMSTR=CRLF` option when importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joe suggested in the comments, unless you need the csv files for another reason, it would be better to create a SAS data library for this.

Another way to do this would be to `proc import` it pretty much the same way you used `proc export`:

```sas
proc import datafile="&Filepath./CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_&thestate..csv"
   out=Work.CA_ISO_policyBYpolicy_&thestate. dbms=dlm replace;
   delimiter=",";
   getnames=yes;  *this will create variable names from your first line;
                  *The opposite of what proc export did;
run;
```

Other thing I can think of is:

```sas
 %let Filepath = /sasdata/sasperm2/act_cfr/fr/SJR/AmFam_vs_ISO_Compare/;
```

Might be causing problems because of the [forward slash.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0o0rjikrg6iezn1ltra79iamibr.htm) Try it like:

```sas
%let Filepath = %str(/sasdata/sasperm2/act_cfr/fr/SJR/AmFam_vs_ISO_Compare/);
```

Also, does the sasdata directory actually exist right on the root directory or is it a subdirectory of the current directory where your sas program is located?  If it's the current directory you need to lose the initial forward slash (or put a . in front of it):

```sas
%let Filepath = %str(./sasdata/sasperm2/act_cfr/fr/SJR/AmFam_vs_ISO_Compare/);
```

Comment: I need the csv files for graph analysis as I have not excelled to doing the graphs in SAS yet. I was formatting my PROC IMPORT command incorrectly so this was great!